# Using Callbacks and Higher-order f(x)'s

Tags: callback, higher-order-functions

I need some assistance with my code.

I'm being asked to create a f(x) that takes an array of strings, then adds an 's' at the end of each string.

My goal is to use DRY code to complete this exercise.

Here's what I have..

```
function pluralize(array, callback) {
 let output = []
  
  for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    let pluralized = callback(animals[i])
    output.push(pluralized)
  }
  return output
}

function addS(str) {
  return str + 's'
}
```

Comment: I figured it out! Disregard please

Comment: You can post the solution to you're code for future comer's incase someone needs.